# Is it possible to automate Silverlight in windowless mode?

Tags: automated-testing, silverlight

Does anybody have an application under test (AUT) that uses a mixture of HTML and Silverlight controls, which they have successfully automated?

My AUT web app has screens with a mixture of HTML and Silverlight, and this requires silverlight to run in [Windowless mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

But, this apparently makes the Silverlight elements opaque to automation (according to [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com)). I've tried a few different automation tools now, without success (they are unable to distinguish elements within the Silverlight area). Before I waste my time trying and failing with every tool there is, does anybody have any experience of this at all?

Comment: Dmitry's answer below is correct.  In addition, a Silverlight plug-in in windowless mode is only an issue if the there is a layer of html displayed over it.  If it is the top layer, you shouldn't see any issues.  If it is not the top layer, that means that you would not need to interact directly with the Silverlight elements because as a user, the html layer would be intercepting all clicks anyways, and you would just interact with those instead.

Answer (score 3):

**TestComplete** [should be able to access internal Silverlight properties](http://support.smartbear.com/articles/testcomplete/automated-unit-testing-of-silverlight-apps), even in Windowless mode.
At the same time it allows to perform functional web testing [[1](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55054/), [2](http://support.smartbear.com/screencasts/testcomplete/intro-to-web-testing/)].

---

And another possible solution...

**You can achieve this when performing SilverLight Isolated API / Unit Testing.

[Here's an example](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/test-with-silverlight-coreclr).**

> Unit tests usually run against SilverLight's Windowless mode. So you can look for Silverlight unit-testing tools and use them in collaboration with web testing tools, e.g. with Selenium WebDriver.

---

Also take look at [this article](http://artoftestinc.blogspot.ru/2007/05/automated-testing-of-silverlight.html).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry; I'm afraid I can't confirm whether TestComplete would work on the app I was testing, as I am on a different job now.